# Unable to migrate Work Item with greater than 25000 revisions

Tags: azure-devops-migration-tools, vsts-sync-migrator

I am using the Azure DevOps Migration Tools and it hits an exception when I try to migrate a work items with 35977 revisions.

Here is my configuration:

[image: .Json file]

Here is the SOAP error I am getting:

[image: Error file]

Comment: Hi, how can I find instructions about how to write configuration file?

Answer (score 1):

Wow, that's a lot of revisions. I'm not sure I have ever seen a work item with that many revisions. I assume that you have some sort of tool that auto updates the work items, which is what is causing this.

> Since it take about 200ms per revision to save Work Items I would
> expect it to 5000 seconds (thats 82h) to migrate just 1 work item with
> that many!

Since the Azure DevOps Migration tools use the old SOAP API (Object Model) this one is out of our hands. There may be some way to page the revisions but I am unaware. If you do find a way to only load partial works items i'd be intersted... although thinking about it I think there is a wi.LoadPartial() method... never used that.

To move forward you could add `AND [System.Rev] < 25000` to your query to not load those work items that have that many revisions.

***This would allow you to continue with the CLosed items that are supported.***

We have added a way to only migrate some of the revisions when there are more, but we never envisaged in our wildest defensive coding strategies that it would be above 1000 revisions. I can imagine memory and other issues cropping up.

---

Added to: https://github.com/nkdAgility/azure-devops-migration-tools/issues/1096

Comment: Thank you Martin for your valuable input. Yes they have lot of revision as they have many custom WIT's. Sure Martin will have a check with the partial WIT ID and update you the same. I will have a check with the condition and will get in touch with the same.